# Emacs scratch buffer Lisp eval

Tags: scratch-buffer

So I'm entirely new to programming but I have been trying to familiarize myself with emacs for future scripting. When I am typing in the scratch buffer, I type certain functions such as defun and while and they are recognized by the buffer and appear in purple. However, with other Lisp functions such as set or +, they do not appear in any color and I was wondering why that is.

Thanks

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: Please be aware that questions about programming _tools_ belong at Stack Overflow. However, there are several Stack Exchange sites for specific tools: emacs is one of them. You can view all of the technology sites **[here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology)**. Always read a site's help center and search for existing questions before asking your own.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using programming tools.

Comment: Also, note that Google Searches make poor titles.  If your question is a good one, you can usually summarize the entire question in your title, rather than stuffing some meaningless keywords in there.